# Writing Gems for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to write a gem that adds some functionalities to MyController in a Rails application. Basically I know how to write a gem, I have already wrote a couple of gems, used them in my Ruby applications. They work fine. But I have never written gems that deals with Rails classes or objects, in particular Controller classes. 
I understand that Rails applications are Ruby applications, but it is at the same time a framework with a lot of out-of-box modules, classes, objects, and underlying structures and conventions.

So, is there any rules/standards/convention that one should follow when writing a gem to use it in Rails application? Maybe best practices?

Comment: Why not just make Rails a dependency in your `gemspec`?

Comment: definitely look at the rails guide on the topic. There is some idiosyncratic code; look at other peoples' gems for examples.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html